# How can I find out what the settings in /sys/bus/usb/devices/<id>/power mean?

Tags: usb, power-management

I am trying to hammer out an issue with one of my USB hard drives constantly falling asleep and waking back up.  I made my way into `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power` .. inside are a number of settings:

```
me@mybox:/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power$ dir
active_duration       control              runtime_status
autosuspend           level                runtime_suspended_time
autosuspend_delay_ms  persist
connected_duration    runtime_active_time
```

Each is a file with a setting in it.. but there is no description of what the settings mean.  For example, if I open `autosuspend` in nano, the only thing inside it is `2` .. nothing else. How can I find out what `2` means, and what the other possible values are?

Thanks

Comment: You are supposed to `echo` to set the value for each setting - e.g. for an intel backlight `echo 300 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` - for yours, `autosuspend` is currently set to `2`, which could be set by `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power/autosuspend`

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-power

Answer (score 2):

Please check here: http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt?v=linux-3.11.10 I suggest you do:

```
sudo -i
echo -1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
exit
```

If that fixes it for you, then make it persistent:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add:

```
echo -1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

Proofread, save and close gedit.